# Tem como simplificar essa quantidade de condições?

Tags: c#, .net, revisão-de-código

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
        foreach (var lote in collection.ToList())
        {
            count++;

            ushort[] dadosBalanca = new ushort[9];

            if (lote.AlvoPasso > ushort.MaxValue)
            {
                var subtracao = (lote.AlvoPasso - 65536);
                dadosBalanca[3] = 1;

                if (lote.AlvoPasso > (ushort.MaxValue * 2))
                {
                    subtracao -= 65536;
                    dadosBalanca[3] = 2; //[OUT37]

                    if (lote.AlvoPasso > (ushort.MaxValue * 3))
                    {
                        subtracao -= 65536;
                        dadosBalanca[3] = 3; //[OUT37]

                        if (lote.AlvoPasso > (ushort.MaxValue * 4))
                        {
                            subtracao -= 65536;
                            dadosBalanca[3] = 4; //[OUT37]
                        }
                    }
                }

                dadosBalanca[4] = (ushort)subtracao; //[OUT38]
            }
            else
            {
                dadosBalanca[3] = 0; //[OUT37]
                dadosBalanca[4] = (ushort)lote.AlvoPasso; //[OUT38]
            }

            //...
        }
```

Este código já funciona, gostaria de sugestão de melhoria.

Comment: Não vejo necessidade de "enxugar" o código, o mesmo está com a sintaxe correta. Qual a necessidade que você está tendo?

Comment: Tem mais código dentro do foreach? Isso é relevante (não o código em si, mas a informação) porque o pode-se querer usar um `continue` para diminuir o nível de indentação.

Comment: Apesar de o código funcionar, pelos comentários nas respostas fica evidente que faltou definir as regras necessárias, então fechei. Pode ser editada para por os parâmetros que faltam e reaberta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem muito o que enfeitar. Você pode substituir aqueles if's encadeados por um `for`.

BTW, os três if's estarem encadeados não faz muito sentido porque eles escrevem no mesmo lugar, ou seja, um sobrescreve o outro. De qualquer forma, eu mantive o comportamento original no `for`.

O código pode ficar assim:

```
foreach (var lote in collection.ToList())
{
    count++;
    ushort[] dadosBalanca = new ushort[9];

    if (lote.AlvoPasso <= ushort.MaxValue) // Note que isso foi invertido
    {
        dadosBalanca[3] = 0; //[OUT37]
        dadosBalanca[4] = (ushort)lote.AlvoPasso; //[OUT38]
        continue;        
    }

    var subtracao = (lote.AlvoPasso - 65536);
    dadosBalanca[3] = 1;

    for(ushort i = 2; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        if (lote.AlvoPasso > (ushort.MaxValue * i))
        {
            subtracao -= 65536;
            dadosBalanca[3] = i; //[OUT3X]    
        }    
    }        

    dadosBalanca[4] = (ushort)subtracao; //[OUT38]    
}
```

Comment: editei sua pergunta mas foi rejeitado, então quero sugerir para você mesmo editar, dentro do for, mudar o var para ushort ou fazer o cast antes de atribuir na posicao dadosBalanca[3] se não da erro, visto que var i=1 assume que i é inteiro e não ushort, e mudar o valor inicial do for para 2, pois a primeira subtração você já fez fora do for. Entendeu?

Answer (score 2):

Sim, dá, bastante:

```
var deslocamento = lote.AlvoPasso / ushort.MaxValue;
dadosBalanca[3] = deslocamento;
dadosBalanca[4] = lote.AlvoPasso - ushort.MaxValue * deslocamento;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/BasicMath.cs).

Estou partindo do princípio que não tem como o deslocamento dar mais que 4, já que o código atual ignora isto. Se puder, vai dar erro no original e no meu, precisaria tratar, mas precisaria ver qual é o critério.

Comment: nesse caso o deslocamento pode ter mais de 4, só não coloquei mais, para não ficar extenso a pergunta, por isso quero melhorar, o critério é sempre multiplicar +1, nesse caso seguir a lógica do if, consegue entender?